# session id not working on server side in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sessionid

I am working in codeigniter. In my current everything is working properly on my local xampp server. But after hosting the project on server session id is not being taken which is causing an error. Code is given below.

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('login_id'=>$row->user_id,'user_name'=> $row->name,'value'=> $this->session->session_id));
```

The same line of code is used in local server for getting session id and it works. I want to is there any issue regarding the server.

Comment: Double check to load session library.

Comment: session library has been loaded with $this->load->library('session');

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your session write directory is writable.

Here you can find about codeigniter sessions. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

`To be more specific, it doesn’t support PHP’s directory level and mode formats used in session.save_path, and it has most of the options hard-coded for safety. Instead, only absolute paths are supported for`$config['sess_save_path']`.

Another important thing that you should know, is to make sure that you don’t use a publicly-readable or shared directory for storing your session files. Make sure that only you have access to see the contents of your chosen sess_save_path directory. Otherwise, anybody who can do that can also steal any of the current sessions (also known as “session fixation” attack).`

Also about php sessions 
http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

**Warning**
If you leave this set to a world-readable directory, such as /tmp (the default), other users on the server may be able to hijack sessions by getting the list of files in that directory.